# typedef'ng a pointer and const

Tags: c, pointers, constants, typedef

I was looking at an example which showed that why typedef'ng a pointer is a bad practice. The part I didn't understand about the example is that why the compiler wasn't able to catch the problem. I elaborated the example into the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int *TYPE; 

void set_type(TYPE t) {
    *t = 12;
}

void foo(const TYPE mytype) {   
    set_type(mytype);  // Error expected, but in fact compiles 
}

int main() {   
    TYPE a;
    int b = 10;
    a = &b;
    printf("A is %d\n",*a);
    foo(a);
    printf("A is %d\n",*a);

    return 0;
}
```

So, I was able to change the value of `a`. Even though, the example explained that you would have to do, `typedef const int *TYPE`, to solve the problem, I dont understand why the compiler was not able to catch the error when I am setting `TYPE to be const` in the function argument itself. I am sure I am missing something very basic.

Comment: Answer, DON'T. `typedef`ing a pointer will cause more problems than the benefits of "*syntax sugar*".

Comment: I am sure you are right, but I am sorry, that was not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Your problem actually stems from hiding pointer semantics. As @iharob wrote: do not `typedef` pointers. That just leads to confusion and subtle errors.6 Note that you cannot change the value of `a` in the functions, but only of `*a`, i.e. `b`. `a` is quite useless, you could have just passed `&b` to `foo` and printed `b` directly.

Comment: As an aside, Microsoft APIs use typedef'ed pointers all over the place, with hilarious results.

Comment: @cdarke Well at least some of them use `const`, e.g. `LPCVOID` versus `LPVOID`, `LPCSTR` versus `LPSTR` etc. But if it wasn't for them being so ingrained in the Microsoft API psyche, one would definitely be better off avoiding them!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue here is confusion about what `const` is being applied to: is it applied to the pointer value itself, or the value being pointed to?

`const TYPE x` is saying that the *pointer value* should be constant. This is roughly equivalent to `int * const x`. Note that the following code *does* result in an error:

```
int b = 10;
const TYPE p = NULL;
p = &b; // error here (assign to const)
```

What you were expecting is `const int * x`, which makes the value *pointed to by x* a constant.

Since the typedef hides the fact that `TYPE` is a pointer type, there's no way to specify that the thing pointed to by `TYPE` should be `const`, aside from declaring another typedef:

```
typedef const int * CONST_TYPE;
```

However, at this point the typedef seems to be causing more trouble than it solves... Probably not the best idea.

Comment: I understood the point you made and now it clears the confusion. however, the last declaration you added was wrong for this question as I was looking for a constant value, not a constant pointer. Can you please edit that so that I can accept the answer.